# Telegram bot only sends one message from twitter stream

Tags: python, tweepy, telegram-bot, twitter-streaming-api, python-telegram-bot

I am trying to create a telegram bot that streams requested tweets to a user, group or channel. Thus far i have been able to stream the tweets to my computer successfully, however, when i try to send the tweets to my telegram bot i only receive a single tweet. I am able to view the tweet-stream on my computer but i can't get telegram to forward each tweet, besisdes the first one as a message.

please have a look at my code, any help would be greatly appreaciated

```
updater = Updater(token=TOKEN)
jB = updater.job_queue
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher


class Listener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):

        # use json to load data
        all_data = json.loads(data)
        tweet = all_data["text"]
        username = all_data["user"]["screen_name"]
        tweet_stream = {"name":username, "twit":tweet}
        print(tweet_data)

#remove retweets from the tweets
if not all_data["retweeted"] and 'RT @' not in all_data["text"]:
    print((username, tweet))

    def bot_message(bot, job):
        bot.send_message(chat_id=job.context, text=(username, tweet))

    def bot_timer(bot, update, job_queue):
        bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text='Tweet 
        will be sent every 5 seconds')

job_queue.run_repeating(bot_message, 5, 
context=update.message.chat_id)

bot_handler=CommandHandler('tweets',bot_timer,pass_job_queue=True)
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(bot_handler)



# *** need to apply the error codes for the error function
def on_error(self, status):
    print(status, "this is an error")
    return True


# List of followers to track
followers =[ "759251", "1333467482", "2592325530", 
"759252279862104064", "1051053836", "884936655437791232", 
"862007728956485632","869908314292924416" ]


twitterStream = Stream(auth, Listener())
twitterStream.filter(follow=followers, async=True)


# telegram to send message

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - 
%(message)s', level=logging.INFO)


start_handler = CommandHandler('start', start)
dispatcher.add_handler(start_handler)

updater.start_polling(timeout=5)
```

Comment: Does the bot resend the first tweet each time or does he send just one ?

Comment: It sends the same tweet each time because i tried using a jobQueue, but before that it would send just one tweet